# Controlling output of a webpage scraped using jsoup

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape [banggood](https://www.banggood.com) for prices of products.

The problem is that the currency I'm getting with jsoup is a random one from the list. I've been looking into the html file to find if something could help me but I didn't find anything.

**How could I control the currency type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the **Network** section of **Chrome's Developer's Tools**, you could see that when you change the currency, the request-header contains the following:

```
:path:/index.php?com=ajax&t=setDefaltCountry&country=104&currency=USD
```

I guess you could use that...

Comment: oh that's interesting but when it loads the page it has another currency for a moment and then changes it for the one that you set. I'm doing a first connection to set the currency and then another to get the price. The first one should it be with jsoup or how?

Comment: ok I did it wrong, just needed one connection adding what you said! Thx